# Convert all parameterized dynamic URLs to SEO friendly URLs in PHP

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I am asking question after so many attempts to do this. Found many results on this website but none of them worked for me.

I have a website built in PHP (no any CMS) that has URLS like

`www.someweb.com/job_detail?job_id=this-is-my-job-no-1`

`www.someweb.com/job_detail?job_id=this-is-my-job-no-2`

`www.someweb.com/job_detail?job_id=this-is-my-job-no-3`

I just want to convert all URLS like these

`www.someweb.com/job_detail/this-is-my-job-no-1`

`www.someweb.com/job_detail/this-is-my-job-no-2`

`www.someweb.com/job_detail/this-is-my-job-no-3`

Here is my .htaccess content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RedirectMatch 404 ^/admin/$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/admin/uploads/$
ErrorDocument 404 /page_not_found.php
<Files index.php>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Have tried many ways but no one solved my issue. Please help me getting fine solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rules:

```
RewriteRule job_detail\/([\w\-]+) job_detail?job_id=$1
Redirectmatch 301 job_detail?job_id=(\w+) job_detail/$1
```

Comment: dear @nicael I have tried both of these but still my URL is parameterized. Can you please edit my .htaccess content. I will paste that same.

Comment: @gojobs Do you want to redirect the first type of URLs to the second ones? Because my answer makes it possible to accese the first URL using the second (just type `/job_detail/this-is-my-job-no-1` and see what happens), but doesn't restrict going to the first type of URL.

Comment: Actually I want to redirect www.someweb.com/job_detail.php?job_id=this-is-my-job-no-1 to www.someweb.com/job_detail.php/this-is-my-job-no-1

I forgot to mention .php in first URL.

and unfortunately your code is not working :( @nicael

Comment: please help me finding the solution @niceal